# Viewing USB in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, usb, bios, linux-mint

I have trouble with viewing USB in BIOS. I wanna install Windows 10 on my laptop and of course to do it i need to run from USB, but BIOS doesn't see it! Another laptop Asus can see USB and even USB with no written OS on it. So the thing isn't in USB.

Before I've installed Linux Mint instead Windows 10, and then BIOS saw USB and everything was good. There's no Legacy boot in BIOS as well.

Maybe I have to update BIOS somehow, or something else?

Photos of BIOS sections:

Main:

[image: Main]

Advanced:

[image: Advanced]

Security:

[image: Security]

Boot:

[image: Boot]

Exit

[image: Exit]

Comment: How did you create the Windows USB stick?

Comment: @user1686
With standard Linux utility USB image writer on Linux Mint

Comment: Using what image? Official Windows ISO images aren't USB disk images.

Comment: The standard USB image writer can't be used for the current Microsoft ISOs. Preferably do it from a Windows computer using the official Media Creation tool that's triggered by the ISO download (Windows only). In Linux you may use MKUSB but not the typical tools that exclusively depend on DD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto 
Ok, if so. But USB should be viewed in BIOS anyway. In another laptop i see it.

Comment: (1) No, not necessarily and typically it doesn't show up when not recognized as a *bootable* device. (2) Done as it was it *may* be recognizable for BIOS/Legacy boot mode but certainly not in the proper UEFI mode. (3) It goes without saying that you want UEFI mode.

Comment: Another great alternative is https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html , the multi ISO loader. Just follow the instructions to install it / make a Ventoy USB drive and then simply copy any supported ISO to its root -> https://www.ventoy.net/en/isolist.html . It boots with a Grub like menu where you can select which ISO to boot. Conveniently you can make a bootable USB with both Linux and Windows installer and/or others.

Answer (score 0):

Re-create your Windows 10 USB Stick using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/)

Rufus automatically identifies Windows 10 ISO installations and will format and write to the USB stick in the correct way. It also offers the option to change from GPT to MBR if your machine is very old.